# Is there a formal or authoritative definition for "dereferencing" in Java?

Tags: java

Coming from a C and C++ background, I have always assumed that dereferencing in Java is the process of accessing an object via its reference.

For example, "ref" is a reference, and it is dereferenced when used to access the Integer object it refers to:

```
    Integer ref = new Integer(7);     
    // Dereference "ref" to access the object it refers to.
    System.out.println(ref.toString());
```

And NullPointerExceptions occur when that dereferencing process fails:

```
Integer ref = null;
// Dereferencing "ref" causes an exception.
System.out.println(ref.toString());
```

However, my interpretation conflicts with one of the topics being tested on Oracle's new [Java SE 8 Programmer I exam (beta)](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-808):

> > *Explain an Object's Lifecycle (creation, "**dereference by reassignment**" and   garbage collection)*

So according to whoever created the Java 8 exam, dereferencing in Java is the act of **reassigning a reference**, rather than the act of **evaluating a reference**:

For example:

```
    // Create an Integer object, and a reference to it.
    Integer ref = new Integer(7); 
    ref = null; 
    // Now (according to Oracle?):
    // - The reassignment means ref has been "dereferenced".
    // - The dereferenced object is now eligible for Garbage Collection.
```

Googling the issue anecdotally suggests that Oracle's definition is more widely used, but that doesn't mean it is correct, and the only hit on google for "dereference by reassignment" is for that new Java 8 exam! The JLS doesn't really shed any light either way.

Is there any formal or authoritative definition (as opposed to personal opinions) on what dereferencing really means in Java? (i.e. Does it relate to evaluation or reassignment?)

It seems strange that two completely different definitions manage to coexist.

Comment: I've personally never heard the word used that way. It looks like they're using it to mean de-reference, as in "remove a reference to". Really poor wording, IMO.

Comment: Did you have a chance to see the answer that Oracle thinks is correct for this question?

Comment: _"It seems strange that two completely different definitions manage to coexist."_ Not to me. Words are overloaded all the time. That said, this particular instance is especially confusing and unfortunate.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Eventually also influenced by thinking about “decrementing the reference count”.  (Since it is mentioned together with “object life time”.)  Even though their JVM does not do reference counting.

Comment: @5gon12eder "Did you have a chance to see the answer that Oracle thinks is correct.."? To be clear, Oracle isn't asking a question; Oracle is presenting that as a topic that should be studied for the Java 8 exam!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a formal or authoritative definition for “dereferencing” in Java?

No.

The places where you would find a *formal definition* of "dereference" would be the JLS or the JVMS.  I looked, and I could not find one.

---

My intuitive understanding is that dereferencing this the process of going from a reference to (loosely) a component of the thing that the reference "points" to.

Here are some examples:

```
x = a.b;  // dereferences the value of 'a' to get the value of field 'b'
a.b();    // dereferences the value of 'a' to get the method 'b'
x = a[1]; // dereferences the value of 'a' to an array and then subscripts it
a[1] = 2; // dereferences the value of 'a' to an array, subscripts it
          // then assigns to the cell

// dereferences the value of 'l' to an object and acquires the
// object's primitive lock
synchronized (l) {
```

As a short hand, whenever you are performing a primitive operation that could throw an NPE, that *involves* dereferencing.

Note that this is NEITHER "assigning a reference" OR (precisely) "evaluating a reference".  For example:

```
boolean truth = ...
String s = truth ? "yes" : null;
```

involves *evaluating* three reference valued expressions and *assigning* a reference, but no dereferencing.   No NPE will be thrown ...

---

OK so is there any support for my interpretation of "dereference" in the Java specifications?  I claim there is.

JLS chapter 17 contains the only uses of the term "dereference" that I can find in the latest edition of the JLS.  In JLS 17.5.1, the semantics of `final` is described as being *"influenced by the Dereference Chain"* which is defined as follows:

> "*Dereference Chain: If an action `a` is a read or write of a field or element of an object `o` by a thread `t` that did not initialize `o`, then there must exist some read `r` by thread `t` that sees the address of `o` such that `r dereferences(r, a)`."*

If you unpick what that is actually saying (in its context), *I claim* they are using the term *dereference* in a way that is consistent with my first example.

<sup>This is also *consistent with* the meaning of the *dereference operator* (`*`) in C and C++; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).  I can also find examples of dereference used in this way in other Oracle documentation; e.g. [Key Features of the Object-Relational Model > Dereferencing REFs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/key-features-object-relational-model.html#GUID-27E79AFF-6360-410F-8900-19A16B1AD8EC).</sup>

Comment: Yep, that directly answers the question, and of course JLS is the most authoritative source of all. Apologies for missing your answer when it was posted.

Answer (score 17):

Although there is no official definition, the word 'dereference' is used in some of the Java error statements.

For example, if you write following code:

```
char ch = 'A';
if (ch.isLetter()) { }
```

You get error: `char cannot be dereferenced`

So, one can say that accessing the state or behaviour of an object using its reference with the help of the `.` operator is dereferencing.

Comment: I guess your assumption is correct. By Joshua Bloch - An added benefit of `nulling out obsolete references` is that, if they are subsequently
`dereferenced` by mistake, the program will immediately fail with a
`NullPointerException`, rather than quietly doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 6):

Java variables are either "primitive types" or "reference types" in [Oracle's terminology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html) (well, other than the special type of null). I came to Java from a C++ background and always found it easiest to think of reference types like pointers as that makes it easiest to understand how they work (though there are [important differences](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer)), however because all non-primitive variables are like that there's no concept of evaluation (no equivalent of C++'s dereferencing of pointers).

So, in your example:

> ```
> Integer ref = new Integer(7); 
> ref = null;
> ```

On the first line an object is created on the heap and ref refers to it.
On the second line ref is changed to refer to null. There are no more references to the object on the heap so it will have become eligible for garbage collection, but until such time as the garbage collector does so it will actually still be there (excluding any clever JVM optimisation of this simple example!).

AFAIK there isn't an official definition of "dereferencing" in Java. Because there isn't the distinction between evaluation and assignment it does make sense, though it's not a term that I think is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Another example of de-referencing is:

```
String value; // the pointer

value = new String("Value 1");
// a "Value 1" String instance is created, referenced by "value" pointer

value = new String("Value 2"); 
// a new String instance created; "value" pointer is re-assigned to it
// the "Value 1" instance is now de-referenced

value = null;
// "Value 2" String instance is de-referenced
```

When an object is no longer referenced, it may be reclaimed by the garbage
collector. Reassignment to other instances of the type *or* null will both de-reference the instance.

Comment: This is at best a non-standard use of the term "dereference", which matches the use in the question but, to be clear, is not what the vast proportion of programmers (including the OP) would understand the term to mean. If you have an authoritative source for this definition of the term, then your answer should cite it; otherwise as far as I know, this answer is based on a misconception.

Comment: I was just trying to provide insights on the "Dereference by reasignment" topic.
"When an object is no longer referenced, it may be reclaimed by the garbage collector." is taken from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.1 which I believe this is an example of. Segments 4.12.3 and 12.6 speak more about references and "no longer referenced" variables. But I found no definitions on "dereferencing" specifically for Java, and this is what I understand by the term (based on experience, not specification) and I might be wrong here.

Comment: Also, semantics of "dereferencing" in C / C++ do not compare well to Java, as there are no pointer variables or dereferencing operators. I do however agree that the naming is confusing, to say the least, as (I believe) this means two very different things in C++ and Java.