# Definition of dereferencing in Java

Tags: java

It must have *a* simple answer, but it seems `dereferencing` is used in more than one meaning. And I doubt what is correct? Here I listed what I found as definition of `dereferencing`:

- set a reference explicitly to `null` ([JAVA Object Lifecycle, de-referencing and garbage collection](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/java-object-lifecycle-de-referencing-and-garbage-collection/))
- reassignment ([OCA: Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I Study Guide: Exam 1Z0-808](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/OCA%3A+Oracle+Certified+Associate+Java+SE+8+Programmer+I+Study+Guide%3A+Exam+1Z0+808-p-9781118957400))
- accessing a member of object by "." operator (

  1. [Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams 1Z0-804 and 1Z0-805](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781430247647)

     > Since calling a static method does not require dereferencing the reference variable [...]
  2. [Referencing and Dereferencing an object in java](https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91831111.html)
  3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36236082/1043882)

Also I searched in [The Java® Language Specification Java SE 11 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/jls11.pdf) and find that it says:

> For each execution, the behavior of reads is influenced by two additional partial
>   orders, the **dereference chain** `dereferences()` and the memory chain `mc()` [...]

So I think third bullet is true. Is that true?

Comment: "dereferencing" an object means following the "pointer" to get to some field or method of the object. "de-referencing" means removing all references to an object (making it eligible for garbage collection). Hopefully it is clear from the context which one they mean.

Comment: @Thilo I think my question is not answered in your pointed post, because there no answer is accepted and also your opinion is different from those answers. But thank you for your reply, I could not think that terms `dereferencing` and `de-referencing` are different and I have to pay attention to the context.

Comment: @hasanghaforian This question was marked as a duplicate of a similar question asked by me, but you have described the situation much better than I did. However, I disagree with your conclusion that the "third bullet is true"; instead I think _all 3 bullets are true_. I agree with Thilo that the context should clarify the specific way in which the term is being used. The use of the term in JLS which you cite is actually a fourth case, but since that does not directly relate to Java programming (it describes an implementation detail), I view it as qualitatively different to the others.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you for your comment. When I asked my question, I thought the third bullet is true, but now I think like you. Also I think it was better that "Thilo" added an answer instead of a comment, then I could accept that.

Comment: Referencing and Dereferencing an object in java ;https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91831111.html - broken link now , so you can delete it  just leave the words maybe ?!